# ifelse statement with factor variable output

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a dataframe `df`

```
  SNP           Effect   A1 A2
8  rs12145743    -0.0203  T  G
31  rs4650994    -0.0210  A  G
26  rs2602836     0.0192  A  G
34  rs4976033     0.0215  A  G
10 rs12525163    -0.0215  T  C
1  rs10282707    -0.0250  T  C
33  rs4917014    -0.0222  T  G
23  rs2293889    -0.0312  T  G
32  rs4871137    -0.0209  T  G
43   rs970548    -0.0258  A  C
27  rs2923084     0.0256  A  G
24  rs2303975     0.0279  A  G
36   rs499974    -0.0263  A  C
35  rs4983559    -0.0197  A  G
13 rs16942887     0.0831  A  G
16 rs17695224    -0.0290  A  G
18   rs181362    -0.0379  T  C
```

I am creating a new variable `new_A1` that will be different depending on the value of `Effect`.

If `Effect`>0, `new_A1` should contain the value of `A1`.

If `Effect`<0, `new_A1` should contain the value of `A2`.

I am trying to do this using the following ifelse statement:

```
df$new_A1 <- ifelse(df$Effect>0, df$A1, df$A2)
```

However, the output is not as expected. `new_A1` contains 1s and 2s, instead of maintaining the values of the factors in the original variables `A1` and `A2`

```
  SNP           Effect   A1 A2 new_a1
8  rs12145743    -0.0203  T  G      2
31  rs4650994    -0.0210  A  G      2
26  rs2602836     0.0192  A  G      1
34  rs4976033     0.0215  A  G      1
10 rs12525163    -0.0215  T  C      1
1  rs10282707    -0.0250  T  C      1
33  rs4917014    -0.0222  T  G      2
23  rs2293889    -0.0312  T  G      2
32  rs4871137    -0.0209  T  G      2
43   rs970548    -0.0258  A  C      1
27  rs2923084     0.0256  A  G      1
24  rs2303975     0.0279  A  G      1
36   rs499974    -0.0263  A  C      1
35  rs4983559    -0.0197  A  G      2
13 rs16942887     0.0831  A  G      1
16 rs17695224    -0.0290  A  G      2
18   rs181362    -0.0379  T  C      1
```

Comment: Convert the columns (A1, A2) to character class.  Right now, it would be factor class. and then `ifelse` would work.

Answer (score 1):

Handling the factor variables `A1` and `A2` as character variables gives appropriate output.

`hdl.dir$new_A1 <- ifelse(hdl.dir$HDL_Effect<0, as.character(hdl.dir$A2), as.character(hdl.dir$new_A1))`

Answer (score 1):

You could try row/col index.  This should work even without converting explicitly 'factor' to 'character' class.

```
 df$new_a1 <- df[3:4][cbind(1:nrow(df),(df$Effect<=0)+1L)]
```